# Can we wrap a SliverList inside a RenderBox type widget like Card?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I was wondering if I can do something like this:

```
Card(child: SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                          <Widget>[children])
```

This is not allowed as Card expects a Renderbox type child.

Comment: no: `Card` constructor expects `Widget child` so any `Widget` can be passed